# No of Antichains

Tags: number-theory

Let S be a set of size n. Consider the poset $({2^S},\subseteq)$.
Let X be any anti-chain. 
Consider P = {(C,M)|$M\in X$ is a set and C is a maximal
chain containing M}.
Show that,
|P|=$\sum_{M\in X} |M|!(n-|M|)!$ and |P|<=n!

Can someone tell me how to proceed ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Show that for any subset $M$ of $S$, there are $|M|!$ maximal chains in $2^M$. All of these have $M$ as their largest element. Then let $Q=\{A\subseteq S:M\subseteq A\}$, and show that there are are $(n-|M|)!$ maximal chains in $Q$; each of them has $M$ as its smallest element and $S$ as its largest element. A maximal chain in $2^S$ that contains $M$ must consist of a maximal chain in $2^M$, the part of the chain ‘below’ $M$, combined with a maximal chain in $Q$, the part ‘above’ $M$. Any lower part can be combined with any upper part.

For the second part of the question, show that each maximal chain in $2^S$ corresponds to a unique permutation of $S$. It helps to realize that its smallest non-empty member is a $1$-element set, its second smallest is a $2$-element set, and so on. (This observation is also helpful for the first part of the question.)